# Alternative to SendMail

Tags: php, web, sendmail

The host that i am currently using has sketchy reliability when attempting to send an email within a script. (I think they are just really harsh about letting any spam getting through and they happen to filter out some legit stuff too). I basically need an alternative. I remember seeing a website that you can register an account with that allows you to send emaild via them, but i cannot remember what it is called... any ideas?

Cheers

Chief17

Comment: googlemail.com? :) However, if you want to send E-Mail with your domain as the sender address, the host's mail servers are the only choice. Best talk to them about this

Comment: Its a free host and they are very good, this is their only downfall but I can see why they would heavily filter it for the free users (spammers). As for google mail check my comment on 'stillstanding's post. Cheers

Comment: Well you cannot expect industry grade reliability from a free host. Even if you find an alternative, you just shift the problem.

Comment: I'm not expecting industry grade reliability, that's why (as mentioned in the question) I need an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Gmail as your SMTP server: http://lifehacker.com/111166/how-to-use-gmail-as-your-smtp-server. Also here: http://www.geekzone.co.nz/tonyhughes/599

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a more direct answer:
Look at PHPMailer as an alternative to sendmail.

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

There are examples in the download including the use of gmail.

As far as email with addresses from your_domain.com, this
can be accomplished utilizing Google apps. The standard
free version allows for 10 users or email addresses.

Edit 2015_09_29:
PHPMailer is now on GitHub. The new address is:
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
Edit 2015_09_29:

Scott

Comment: PHPMailer is a bit glitchy sometimes. It might be the most known but it is not the best. Best to write your own. It's not to complicated and you can find a lot of samples online.